# Info.plist crashes when trying to edit

Tags: xcode, crash

I am trying to edit my Info.plist in my Xcode project but everytime I try to edit and save (or just leave the file) it freezes. This even happens when I try to edit it in the TextEdit application outside of Xcode. I have tried to clean the project but it is not working.

Comment: You can't modify any file from the app bundle

Comment: Does this issue exist on other Xcode projects or only this one?

Answer (score 0):

I was pulling my hair out over this. Xcode or TextEdit was just freezing with the spinning rainbow circle.

I did a clean on the product then restarted my MacBook and tried again. Thankfully that sorted it, hope it sorts yours too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit plist file in VSCode - it helps me